# Discord bot, TypeError: event() missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, discord.py

When I run the code below for a Discord bot that logs all chat messages, I get an error.

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import logging

discord.Client
client = discord.Client()


logging.basicConfig(filename='std.log',
                    filemode='a',
                    format='%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

client = commands.Bot


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}')
    logging.debug('bot running')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print("-----------------------------------")
    print(message.author)
    print(message.content)
    print("-----------------------------------")
    logging.info('-----------------------------------')
    logging.info(message.author)
    logging.info(message.content)
    logging.info("-----------------------------------")


token = os.environ['TOKEN']
client.run(token)
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 19, in <module>
    async def on_ready():
TypeError: event() missing 1 required positional argument: 'coro'
```

I have tried importing `asyncio` and `discord` but that didn't help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Hint: in your own words, where the code says `client = discord.Client()`, what do you think this means? Specifically, what do you think the `()` part means? Now, see where the code later says `client = commands.Bot`? In your own words, why not have `()` here? (Did you try to read the documentation?) (If you are having difficulty understanding the concepts here, **please read and follow a Python tutorial** all the way to the end, before trying to implement a Discord both. Otherwise, this seems like a typo.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`commands.Bot` is a class. In order to create an instance of it, you need `commands.Bot()`. Without creating your instance of `Bot`, you can't successfully give it event handlers and run it.

Note that you already defined `client` as an instance of `discord.Client`, but then you *redefine* it as the class `commands.Bot`. `Bot` is a subclass of `Client` that adds extra features. You're not using `Bot`'s command functionality, so you could simply remove it and stick with `Client`.